# Use controller Concern inside Sidekiq Worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, activesupport-concern

I have a Sidekiq Worker like this:

```
class PrintWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(action,data)
    parsed_data = JSON.parse(data)
    if action=="tiquet"
      print_tiquet(parsed_data)
    elsif action=="summary"
      print_summary(data[0],data[1])
    end
  end
end
```

were "print_tiquet" and "print_summary" are methods inside a controller concern called Printable.

Is there any way to include this concern inside the worker class? Actually I tried without luck:

require "printable"
include Printable

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention your directory structure, but I'll guess:

- controllers

  - concerns

    - printable.rb
- workers

  - print_worker.rb

Then you'll need to do

```
require 'concerns/printable'
```

Note the lack of additional path such as 'controllers' - Rails doesn't actually care in which `[thing]` in your `app/[thing]/` structure the concern is. It could be in `models/concerns` or `controllers/concerns` - either way, with `require 'concerns/my_concern'` it will just work.

You should probably read [this info here on how Rails (v3) loads paths](http://hakunin.com/rails3-load-paths).

Note: tested in Rails 4

Answer (score 0):

In a Rails 5.2 app, `require 'concerns/printable'` did not work for me, but `include Printable` did work. E.g.

```
class PrintWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Printable

  ...
end
```